# Why do we love bad content?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521009/6879826), which is a code-only answer that isn't in the right language, on a question that is three years old with several other answers. It isn't even in the ballpark of the right language: the question is tagged [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) and [racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/racket), but the "answer" seems to be some mess of C or C++.

My flag was declined. It seems like VLQ flags are very inconsistently handled, and I don't like to use them; but this is obviously an *attempt* at an answer. Sometimes a VLQ flag will stick on an answer like this, so I chose that.

I really don't understand why the community and mods would want to keep this sort of junk around on the site.

Comment: What was the decline message?  That will shed some light on what happened

Comment: @psubsee2003 -- just the usual canned "_declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer_"

Comment: I think we lack a post like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/11407695) (NAA) but for flagging VLQ. It causes too much confusion (to be honest, the flag itself causes too much trouble). What you've linked to is not VLQ, at least it is not that by definition (it was rightfully declined *by the book* of the law, as for the spirit of it - not sure)

Comment: So first, I notice the post in question doesn't have any votes (up or down).  I don't like telling people how to vote, but first thing i do when I see an answer I think is so awful that it needs to be removed is to downvote it.   But as has been mentioned numerous times, standard flags are a terrible way to flag stuff that looks like an answer but isn't.  Mods aren't domain experts.  They see a post that looks like an answer is going to decline a NAA or VLQ flag.  If you have something that looks like an answer but isn't, you should use a custom flag and explain why it isn't really an answer.

Comment: Those types of Answer can be removed by 20K delete votes. Which I believe is the primary reason for that privilege.

Comment: "Sometimes a VLQ flag will stick on an answer like this, so I chose that." Unfortunately, the Low Quality Posts queue [frequently mishandles posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/208273), leading to confusing results for flaggers.

Answer (score 5):

Diamond moderators (the people who actually handle the flags) **are not guaranteed to have the expertise to discern if an answer is actually an answer or is applicable to the question**, period.

So flagging an answer that looks wrong or is factually not correct is not the way to do it.  Flags are meant for content that is spam or offensive.

The ***community*** (the people who don't handle flags) is better equipped to handle bad answers.  Downvote the answer if it's poor and *leave it at that*, since that usually sends a strong enough signal to anyone looking for an answer that maybe, just *maybe*, this answer ain't the one.

Note: don't *ever* presume that we love bad content.  The mechanism in which you express your dissatisfaction with content should be well known and understood to you with 15k+ reputation by now.

Comment: "Flags are meant for content that is spam or offensive." ...or completely incomprehensible, in a language other than the one used on the site, or otherwise not in any way an answer.

Comment: @RyanM sorry, the mod-flag dashboard only shows the question title prominently, doesn't show the question tags at all, and to see the whole question body needs additional 2 clicks.